# Two different forms of the electromagnetic wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations, geometric-optics

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation) that the electromagnetic wave equation written in terms of the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\left(v_{ph}^{2}\nabla ^{2}-{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}}\right)\mathbf {E} = \mathbf{0} \end{aligned}}}$$

However, I have seen the electromagnetic wave equation written as

$$\nabla^2 E + k^2 E = 0$$

in the context of rays.

I would appreciate it if someone could please take the time to explain why these two equations are different, and what is the connection between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation is the Fourier transform of the first one with the frequency symbol taken as $k$.

Answer (score 1):

You get your second equation from your first one if you choose $E$ in such a way that all dependence on $t$ is presented  by a factor $\exp(-i\omega t)$ or $\sin(\omega t +\varphi)$.